# docker-compose is not copying new config file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had default file in `docker/nginx.conf` I edited it, but when I log into Docker image, there is unedited default config file. I don't know why Docker wont copy this specific file with actuall version and copy default one, but others are in the container properly showing.

Here is my Dockerfile where I copy files

```
COPY docker/configuration.docker.py /opt/netbox/netbox/netbox/configuration.py
COPY configuration/gunicorn_config.py /etc/netbox/config/
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/netbox-nginx/nginx.conf
COPY docker/docker-entrypoint.sh /opt/netbox/docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY startup_scripts/ /opt/netbox/startup_scripts/
COPY initializers/ /opt/netbox/initializers/
COPY configuration/configuration.py /etc/netbox/config/configuration.py
```

I am using Dockerfile from netbox-docker image from here:

```
https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox-docker/blob/release/docker-compose.yml
```

And also docker-compose from same image as above:

```
https://github.com/netbox-community/netbox-docker/blob/release/Dockerfile
```

Comment: What are the actual steps you're running to rebuild and restart the container?

Comment: I am stoping and starting with docker compose 
docker-compose down -v and docker-compose up -d

Comment: Can you extend this to be a [mcve]?  That means including enough of the Dockerfile to be able to build and run the image (is there a `VOLUME` directive?) and the `docker-compose.yml` file that starts the container (do `volumes:` hide the image content?).

Comment: @DavidMaze added additional info with URLs

Comment: Changes to your dockerfile aren't picked up with docker-compose up - you have to rebuild the image. Did you do that?

Comment: Why is that needed? When I added for example certificate to some folder, rebuild was not needed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is need to rebuild image, but I can also acces volumes via `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` and that solves my problem before building.